# Add additional column to query based on dates in another table

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I'm looking to query the **datatbl** table and return the table with an additional column based on the *Start_date* values of the **productstbl** table.

Below I have created a schema with the initial table (datatbl_before) and the desired end result (datatbl_after), where a *Product_Lookup* column has been added to the **datatbl** table and shows the corresponding *Product* from the **productstbl** based on the *Asset_ID* of the line and the *Start_date*.

For example, in the first row of **datatbl**, the row relates to Asset_ID '1' and occurred on 2017-08-16, this would retrieve the product value 'A' from the **productstbl** table as it is after the *start_date* value 2017-08-12, but before the next *start_date* value of 2017-09-27 related to that Asset_ID .

In the case where there is no proceeding date for the Asset_ID lookup and start_date, a 'NONE' value could be returned - e.g. Row 5 of **datatbl**

Can anyone provide any direction or advice on how to tackle this one?

Many thanks in advance!

```
CREATE TABLE datatbl_before (
    PDate DATE,
    Asset_ID varchar(255),
    Rev int
);
CREATE TABLE datatbl_after (
    PDate DATE,
    Asset_ID varchar(255),
    Rev int,
    Product_Lookup varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE productstbl (
    Asset_ID varchar(255),
    Start_date DATE,
    Product varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO productstbl
VALUES 
('  1  ','  2017-08-12' ,'  A'  ),
('  1'  ,'  2017-09-27' ,'  B'  ),
('  1'  ,'  2018-02-14' ,'  C'  ),
('  2'  ,'  2018-01-17' ,'  A'  ),
('  2'  ,'  2018-02-21' ,'  B'  ),
('  2'  ,'  2018-03-05' ,'  C'  );

INSERT INTO datatbl_before
VALUES 
('  2017-08-16' ,'  1'  ,'  10'),
('  2017-09-29' ,'  1'  ,'  15'),
('  2018-02-13' ,'  1'  ,'  12'),
('  2018-02-19' ,'  1'  ,'  10'),
('  2018-01-01' ,'  2'  ,'  12'),
('  2018-01-25' ,'  2'  ,'  33'),
('  2018-02-25' ,'  2'  ,'  67'),
('  2018-03-07' ,'  2'  ,'  71');

INSERT INTO datatbl_after
VALUES 
('  2017-08-16' ,'  1'  ,'  10' ,'  A'  ),
('  2017-09-29' ,'  1'  ,'  15' ,'  B'  ),
('  2018-02-13' ,'  1'  ,'  12' ,'  B'  ),
('  2018-02-19' ,'  1'  ,'  10' ,'  C'  ),
('  2018-01-01' ,'  2'  ,'  12' ,'  NONE'),
('  2018-01-25' ,'  2'  ,'  33' ,'  A'  ),
('  2018-02-25' ,'  2'  ,'  67' ,'  B'  ),
('  2018-03-07' ,'  2'  ,'  71' ,'  C'  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub query, which goes and selects the data you want, using data from the outer query in the where clause. In this case, it finds all the products that are the right asset, and started before or on the transaction date, sorts them so the most recent one is first (the one we want) and takes only that one (The TOP 1 part).

The ISNULL part changes any missing values from NULL to 'NONE'

```
Select DB.*, 
    ISNULL(
        (Select top 1 product 
            from productstbl 
            where Asset_ID = DB.Asset_ID 
                and Start_date <= DB.PDate 
            order by Start_date desc
        )
    , 'NONE') as Product_Lookup
from datatbl_before DB;
```